# Compare a logical data frame and a numeric data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames:

```
> df1
  a   b  c
1 1a 11 21
2 2a 12 22
3 3b 13 23
4 4b 14 24
5 5b 15 25
> df2
  a      b     c
1 1a  TRUE  TRUE
2 2a FALSE FALSE
3 3b  TRUE FALSE
4 4b  TRUE  TRUE
5 5b FALSE FALSE
```

I need to keep only the `TRUE` values of `df1` and replace the `FALSE` values with `NA` like this:

```
> df3
  a     b     c
1 1a   11    21
2 2a   NA    NA
3 3b   13    NA
4 4b   14    24
5 5b   NA    NA
```

I've been thinking to use a `for` loop to check each positions of the data frames (only b and c columns) but I wonder if there's a base function or package that I could use.

PS. I need column **a** to be present all the time in the process in order to not get lost.
Thank you all.

Comment: Will all values of `a` be the same in both datasets?

Comment: Yes, df2 is a product of the operator > applied to df1. Both data frames have the same a column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that both data.frames have the same values of `a` in the same order, you can do

```
if(all(df1$a==df2$a)) {
    is.na(df1[,-1]) <-!df2[,-1]
    # alternatively
    # df1[,-1][!as.matrix(df2[,-1])] <- NA
}
```

The `is.na` function allows reassignment and will place NA values wherever the right hand side is TRUE

Comment: It worked. Since `a` column is identical for both data frames I omitted the `if` clause and only used `is.na(df1[,-1]) <-!df2[,-1]`. Thank you.